# Keep your Pharo image up to date

Tags: pharo

I'm using the latest Pharo beta image (1.1) from http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/27025/Pharo-1.1-11367-Betadev10.05.1.zip

Now, core images have an update button that updates things to the state of the art. What do you do on non-core images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply wait that somebody release a new one. The situation is like that since extra packages could break when core is updated and we could not control it.  This is not optimal but for now we cannot do better.